# Is it possible to have a bot read a dm message discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

So I am making a discord bot and I am making it for 2 servers so I made the bot message me and then I tried to make it wait for a response from me which is either "eb" or "guap" and depending on which one I pick it defines the channel. Heres what I have

```
client.once('ready', async () => {
    // [beta]
   
    const storedBalances = await Users.findAll();
    storedBalances.forEach(b => currency.set(b.user_id, b));
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
    client.users.cache.get('461694991467544577').send('what server').then((msg) => {
        console.log("are we making it this far")
        msg.channel.awaitMessages({ filter: (m) => { return true }, max: 1 }).then((collected) => {
            console.log(collected);
            if (collected.first().content === "guap") {
                client.channels.fetch("724610473982558221").then((c) => {
                    channel = c;
                })
                console.log("fetching guaps server");
            }
            if (collected.first().content === "eb") {
                client.channels.fetch("961598555515158568").then((c) => {
                    channel = c;
                })
                console.log("fetching eb's server");
            }
        }).catch(()=>{
            console.log("AwaitMessages Failed");
        })
    });

});
```

Comment: What's the issue here? Please detail that in your question

Comment: I cant get it to await for my message in the dm, it doesnt see the message so its not sending the value of what channel is being assigned, eb is for one servers channel id and guap is for another so If I say eb it will be assigning the channel id to whatever I made it in the code

Comment: When you are creating a client, have you added the `DIRECT_MESSAGES` intent? If not, please add that intent and try again.